# How many amps electrical panel

Tags: electrical-panel, solar

How many amps is my electrical panel and what size solar can I add?

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Xhg.jpg)

Comment: A photo with the covers off might help give you a better answer. Make sure it's clear enough to read any important writing on the breakers.

Comment: Does it look like the bottom one is the main panel and the top one is a sub panel?

Comment: They're labelled "Light(?) Main" and "Lower Main", so I'd guess that these are connected together close enough to be considered to both be part of the main panel (according to code when they were installed). Again, a photo with the covers off might make it easier to answer.

Comment: Yes, this bears a resemblance to a "Rule of Six" / split-bus panel.  Maybe that's what the lower section is.  If so, it's spectacularly overstuffed.   OP are there any panel labels anywhere showing layout of the panel?  Any OTHER boxes e.g. near  your meter?

Comment: Yes, is there a box near your meter with breakers in it?  Can you post photos showing your electric meter and any hardware next to it for that matter?

Comment: I would be looking for a main at another location, there are so many issues many issues for these to be rule of 6 panels (I have never seen one wired this bad) double panels was a way to get around the maximum breaker count so each one may have a separate feeder with both being main lug panels and a true main close to the meter.

Comment: This is right next to the meter

Comment: It looks like you have lots of open spaces solar doesn't take away from your panels ampacity. Photos of any labels even of the meter enclosure. There is nothing here to really even make a guess.

Comment: See https://i.ibb.co/PG85yrj/11-B125-D1-D6-DB-41-D9-83-A0-72-B2-F9-F43-EA6.jpg

Comment: My understanding is for solar I need to add a 30 amp breaker. Also I want to add a pool heat pump heater which needs 60 amp. Since I have space can I add both? See my post above for picture of the meter

Comment: I'll admit, I don't know much about solar panels, but I didn't think their installation required any equipment on the distribution side of the panel.

Comment: It mentions that they need to the follow the 120% rule where a 100amp system will limit me to a 4kw solar system

Comment: @user2808109 -- can you post close-up shots of the face of the electric meter as well as that small sticker/label on the inside of the panel door please?

Comment: @user2808109 -- also, who do you have for an electric utility, for that matter?